# Google Earth - Force KML polygon on top of image overlay

Tags: raster, polygon, google-earth, jpg

In Google Earth:

Step 1.  Create polygon layer.
Step 2.  Overlay image file (mine is in jpg format).
Step 3.  Move polygon layer above and below image file in the "My Places" menu.

I cannot figure how to get the polygon layer to overlay on top of the image file.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Set your image to "Relative to Sea Floor" to fix the polygon having missing edges.

Answer (score 1):

Under Properties, set the polygon Altitude as `Relative to ground`, instead of `Clamped to ground`. The image overlay Altitude should be set as `Clamped to ground`.

Comment: thank you!  I'll give it a shot and comment here

Answer (score 1):

Although this approach CAN work, often the edges of polygons, etc., are not seen because of how they lay across terrain.  It would be better to have some kind of ORDER setting, but the current availability for that within GE is not very good or dependable for this desired solution.